# How to handle "An Item with the same key has already been added" when adding .jar to dot42 project

Tags: dot42

I am trying to add a .jar library to a dot42 project.  specifically Ksoap2-android.  When I add it to a newly created project, I get the error "An Item with the same key has already been added".  What causes this and how do I deal with it?

Comment: https://github.com/dot42/dot42/issues/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in version 1.0.1.81, now available for download.

Comment: I have updated and have added the ksoap2-android library.  I now get an error from Visual Studio 2012 that says that a chunk that should be 0x180 reads 0x100.  I just posted a SO question about it.